# Mongo nested object array update

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update a value in a document and i haven't seen an example that shows me what i need to do.  Here is how my document looks:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429e8a53150d03d541c7a53"),
    "foo" : {
        "bar" : {
            "0" : {
                "email" : {
                    "0" : "bob@aol.com"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is of course not my real object but represents the structure.  how do i update bob@aol.com to be whatever@whocares.net ?

Also how would i remove this same element?

Also (for bunus points) how would i update this using the php Mongo class?

Comment: Are you using any sort of PHP library to interact with the returned mongo json objects?

Comment: The application I'm working on uses this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php  which i am aware is deprecated but i'm assuming the rest of the app also relies on it so changing this is not necessarily easy.  There was some attempt at writing a wrapper around this class but it was not done very well so i'd rather avoid it.

Comment: FYI, this was my first attempt, which did not work:  db.test.update({"foo.bar.0":"email"},{$set:{"0":"whatever@whocares.net"}});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out.  This is how you do it in the console:

```
db.test.update({"foo.bar.0.email" : {"0":"bob@aol.com"} },{$set:{"foo.bar.0.email.0":"whatever@whocares.net"}});
```

And this is how you do it in PHP using the Mongo class

```
$db = new Mongo("connection stuff");

$condition = array('foo.bar.0.email' => array('0' => 'bob@aol.com'));
$data = array('$set' => array('foo.bar.0.email.0' => 'whatever@whocares.net'));

$db->test->update($condition, $data);
```

I hope this helps someone because it took me several hours to figure this out.